NGINX Remove Subdirectory From Path
Preface
I want to start out by saying I know there are at least 200 different SO posts on this exact issue, i've been over every one of them, to summarize for anyone else who stumbles upon this.
Issue
I have a NGINX container (Nginx01) that is acting as the front end to a php-fpm server.  I want the NGINX server to respond to http://.com/wiki/ but strip the /wiki/ part of the URL before sending it to the backend server.  I want to do this specifically to avoid making unnecessary changes to the mediawiki container although I am starting to feel that would be easier at this point...
Background Information
A single volume is shared between both containers hosting the website files. PHP files are hosted through the php-fpm container, all static files should be hosted through NGINX.
Key Tips I've Found
Be mindful of the slashes (/)
Remember that proxy pass + whats captured in the "(.*)" gets combined and thats your final URL. Ensure that you are not adding too many or too little slashes. (Ex1. http://localhost//subdir | Ex2; http://localhostsubdir)
rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)$ $1 break;

Ensure you have break in the command.
Ensure that the break command is located at the end of the rewrite command to ensure it stops processing.
rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)$ $1 break;

What I have tried
This will only be a small subset of my attempts based on items I found on StackOverflow and ServerFault
Before:         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
After:         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /$fastcgi_script_name;

Before:
    location ~ \.php {
        ...

After 1:
    location ~ \.php {
        alias /var/www/html/;

After 2:
    location ~ \.php {
        root /var/www/html/;

Before: fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
After 1: fastcgi_split_path_info ^wiki/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
After 2: fastcgi_split_path_info ^/wiki/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
After 3: fastcgi_split_path_info ^/wiki(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

Before:
location /wiki/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki01/html/;

After:
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki01/html/;


Before: location ~ \.php {
After: location ^~ /wiki/(.+\.php) {

Before:
        location @php_rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
        }

After 1: rewrite ^wiki/(.*)$ /index.php;
After 2: rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)$ /index.php;
After 3: rewrite ^/wiki(.*)$ /index.php;

Configuration File(s) & Log(s)

nginx.conf
...
    # Build a php rewrite location
    location @php_rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
    }
...

mediawiki01.conf
location /wiki {
    # Redirect /wiki to /wiki/
    return 301 /wiki/;
}

location /wiki/ {

    # Define the root directory where MediaWiki resources are mounted.
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki01/html/;

    # Remove the /wiki prefix before passing the request to backend
    rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)$ $1 break;

    # Proxy settings to forward requests to MediaWiki PHP-FPM (for non-PHP files or if necessary)
    proxy_pass http://mediawiki01:9000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    # Try to serve files directly and fallback to index.php, adjusted for rewritten URI
    try_files $uri @php_rewrite;

    # Allow access to approved file types only.
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to the /mw-config directory
    location ^~ /wiki/mw-config/ {
        internal;
    }

    # Location block to handle PHP file execution using FastCGI
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Pass the PHP requests to FastCGI server listening on mediawiki01 at port 9000
        # This is typically the address and port where your PHP-FPM server (MediaWiki) is running
        fastcgi_pass mediawiki01:9000;

        # Define the default file to serve when a directory is requested
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # The regex to split the PATH_INFO part from the SCRIPT_FILENAME
        # It captures the PHP file path as well as any additional path info
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        # Set the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter that will be passed to FastCGI server
        # It combines the document root and the script name to form the absolute path to the PHP script
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Explicitly setting HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        # Include the standard parameters provided for FastCGI requests
        # This file contains presets that are commonly required for FastCGI processing
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
}


MediaWiki01 Logs
Logs are still showing that the /wiki/ is being included in the URL.
172.18.0.3 -  18/Jun/2024:10:00:04 +0000 "GET /wiki/index.php" 404

Nginx01 Logs
172.22.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2024:11:15:34 +0000] "GET http://localhost/wiki/index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 40407 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "0.000" "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" "/usr/share/nginx/html"
2024/06/18 11:15:34 [alert] 19#19: *2 "alias" cannot be used in location "/wiki/" where URI was rewritten, client: 172.22.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /wiki/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"

